# Sum of two Erlang distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I am given $n$ lightbulbs and $m$ lightbulbs to replace burnt off lightbulb. All $n$ lightbulbs are working at the same time.
I need to find pdf of time before there is no replacement lightbulb, $m = 0$.
Lightbulb failure time follows exponential distribution with rate $a$.

As far as I know, sum of independent exponential distributions gives me Erlang distribution. So, I have a sum of two Erlang distributions. Does it mean that pdf will be described as:

$$\left(\frac{a^{m+n}x^{m+n-1}e^{-ax}}{m+n-1}\right)!$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: The question is not quite clear. Please rephrase it better.